# gotroot mod_security rules

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-security

Are the [gotroot mod_security rules](http://www.gotroot.com/mod_security+rules) any good?

I've heard that you will get a lot of false positives and before I try and use them on a live box just wanted to know if anyone else has experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried them myself but this [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181052/modsecurity-rules-which-are-better-gotroot-or-trustwave) is instructive.  It seems there are false negatives as well as all the mentions of false positives you can find in Google.